# Pandas Not Reading Excel Properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to use and Add-In for Excel that gets removed when I use win32com.client forcing me to restart my computer. I have found a work around using xlrd, openpyxl, and pandas but I have run into a completely new issue.

I first open Excel with the pandas and read through the file extracting the information that I require.

```
xl = pandas.ExcelFile(xlsx)
sheets = xl.sheet_names
df = xl.parse(sheets[2])
```

I then have to go into the same workbook and update the Meter Name and the date.

```
for i, value in enumerate(dataList):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsx)
    worksheets = wb.sheetnames
    worksheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(worksheets[0])
    rowCoordinate = i
    meterName = value[0]
    creationDate = value[1]
    units = value[2]

    worksheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value = meterName
    wb.save(copyXlsx)
    dateList = []
    for k, dateRange in enumerate(value[3]):
        sDate = dateRange[0]
        eDate = dateRange[1]
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(copyXlsx)
        worksheets = wb.sheetnames
        worksheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(worksheets[0])
        worksheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value = sDate
        worksheet.cell(row=3, column=2).value = eDate
        wb.save(copyXlsx1)
        print meterName, dateRange

        xl1 = pandas.ExcelFile(copyXlsx1)
        sheets = xl1.sheet_names
        df = xl.parse(sheets[0])
        print df
```

My issue is that the excel file opens and write the information perfectly. but pandas has all the header information updated but the numbers are the same from the original document. I have gone in and explored the Intermediate Excel Document and it doesn't match the number pandas shows

Comment: You do save save data and make changes `inplace`?

Comment: @zipa I am not sure what you mean. This is the first time I have been working with these modules. I have read a lot of tutorials. 

The only save I do is the workbook save function from openpyxl. What is saving `inplace`